# Gridview keypress event to go next cell of it

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem in "gridview" of application where I want to change the cell by enter rather then tab key.

I GOT SOME OF CODE LIKE THIS ON keyPress and keyDown event....

```
private void GridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
}
```

but it works after I would have data already in it.

I want is to pressing enter its must work like tab at the new row is generated in gridview

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this..

To handle the KeyDown and KeyPress events for the editing control just handle the EditingControlShowing event and access the events on the editing control. Check out this link   for [more info](http://www.windowsforms.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc)

That said, you do have to derive from the DataGridView to do what you want. This is due to the way that keyboard handling works for contained controls.

Here is the code you need to make the Enter key move the focus to the right:

```
public class dgv : DataGridView
{
 protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
 {
    Keys key = (keyData & Keys.KeyCode);
    if (key == Keys.Enter)
    {
        return this.ProcessRightKey(keyData);
    }
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
 }
 protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        return this.ProcessRightKey(e.KeyData);
    }
    return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
  }

}
```

I hope it will helps you...

Comment: The solution for overriding the ProcessDialogKey and ProcessDataGridViewKey methods did the trick just fine! Thanks for the nice solution. This is also explained at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.processdatagridviewkey.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good post on how to create a row dynamically on a button click. The only difference is that you need to call it on a key press so you would just modify it to suit your need.

http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/articles/51360.aspx

Comment: Read OP. He/She has winform app.